# angular2 how to import Window

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created a global env variable called `env.js` which I can use outside angular, however I want to use the same env variable in angular2.

```
(function (window) {
 window.__env = window.__env || {};
   window.__env.baseUrl= 'http://www.examplesite.com/1';
  window.__env.otherUrl = 'http://www.examplesite.com/2';
  window.__env.baseUrl = '/';
}(this));
```

however when I use `window.__env.baseUrl` it gives me an error of `.__env.baseUrl` does not exist on type `Window`. So just wondering how can I import `Window` so it'd allow me to use `.__env.baseUrl`.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the compiler checks the type, and it only knows the "common" properties of the window object.

You can "use" global variables like this:

```
declare var xxx: any;

export class .... {

}
```

In your case it would be:

```
declare var __env: any;
```

Comment: and this would be in the `typings.ts`?

Comment: @MrNew no, you can use this in any class, just put that before the class declaration

Comment: Thanks although its still showing the same error :/

Comment: Then I used it like this `window.__env.baseUrl` after declaring it?

Comment: figured it out now `(<any>window).__env.baseUrl`

Comment: You should use it directly like `__env.baseUrl`